# How to get Windows-like pinch zoom or -scaling on Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, 22.04, touchpad, zooming

I just switched from Windows to Ubuntu. I used the pinch to zoom/scaling feature a lot while browsing on Windows but looks like this feature isn't available by default on Ubuntu. How do I enable this feature?

Comment: You can zoom in and out with 2 fingers moving up or down the touchpad. I came here with the same question though.

Answer (score 0):

There are two sides of the problem - first if your actual hardware passes right signal and second if the specific application interprets it as you intended.
It's hard to answer as you've written nothing about your distribution and hardware. Also can you define what you mean by 'windows-like' and particular use case ? A lot of gestures on Linux are application specific , e.g in Firefox and Chrome by changing some options you can change behaviour of Google Maps.
In Firefox you can start with checking the value of 'apz.allow_zooming' after typing about:config in address bar